# Facebook how to grouping the wall post with a specefic name

Tags: android, facebook

i need to upload a image and  description but it will be appeared in the following format . i have tried with **me/feed** but it create a separate entry for each post. i need to group the item as in the images, please help me.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure that can be done using the Graph API. I have never seen an API function that allows that. I know, if you post multiple photos in a very short span, Facebook will club them together. But I am not aware of that functionality being exposed to their API. Are you sure this can be done using the API?

Comment: this happend when i share the content throug iphone app and am trying to create in android alos

Comment: Are you doing something different while posting from the iPhone app? And, perhaps I should have led with this, is it an app you are developing and have access to the code? For the iPhone app that is.

Comment: some one has wrote the iphone app i have just mimic the app. I don't know how they are doing like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar behavior can be achieved by creating your own [actions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/actions/) and [aggregations](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/aggregations/)

But this would require the direct user interaction with your app and I don't know if it's your case.

Comment: am able to post a single object but in my case i have an array of object ,is it possible to post array of objects in single request or i have to do it in a loop .  "object":"www.myobject.html"

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Answer (score 1):

Your picture can be one of two things:

1- Open Graph Aggregation:

The app in your picture could be using the [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/) part of the Facebook API. The idea behind Open Graph is to allow the user to express more specific, high-level actions beyond like, comment and share. Open Graph does this by letting the developer define custom actions and custom objects for the app. The Open Graph API also lets the developer to define [Aggregations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/aggregations/) for an app, which is what your picture possibly shows:

> Aggregations are summary stories on Timeline that are defined by your application to showcase the Open Graph activities of a user in a structured and interesting way.

2 - Aggregation by Facebook

Facebook aggregates contents to create a better user experience by joining together repetitive contents in one post. The logic and timing for this is not disclosed or part of the API.